# HOCON format for cluster router group?

Tags: akka.net

I've set up one Akka.Net node to be the seed node in a cluster,which I call frontend, and another node which I call backend. In the frontend node I configure a cluster router group in code which makes it possible for me to send messages from the frontend to any nodes joining with the role 'backend' (in a round robin fashion) and that have an actor at /user/backend. The code that I have that is working looks like this:

```
system.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(
    new ClusterRouterGroup(
        new RoundRobinGroup("/user/backend"),
        new ClusterRouterGroupSettings(10, false, "backend", ImmutableHashSet.Create("/user/backend"))
)));
```

Now I want to move this configuration to the config file instead (hocon). How would I go about doing that so that I only need the following code to instantiate it?

```
system.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(FromConfig.Instance), "backend");
```

My attempt has only yielded exceptions with no clues.

```
/backend {
  router = round-robin-group
  routees.paths = ["/user/backend"]
  cluster {
    enabled = on
    max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
    allow-local-routees = off
    use-role = backend
  }
}
```

Any good hints? The only information I'm getting in the exception is:

```
Configuration problem while creating [akka://ClusterSystem/user/backend] with router dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox  and routee dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox [].
```

Comment: can you paste your whole HOCON section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the full HOCON config. Seems like you just want a cluster-aware group router. Nothing obvious jumps out at me, but here are a few things that come to mind where I'd start looking:

1. Have you specified your seed node? The `frontend` needs itself as a seed node too. It will "join itself" to start the cluster.
2. Double check that you have all the necessary elements for `Akka.Cluster` in HOCON, including specifying the `akka.cluster` and `akka.remote` HOCON sections.
3. Is the config for `/backend` inside the proper HOCON section? Needs to be in `akka.actor.deployment`.
4. You don't need the `max-nr-of-instances-per-node` flag for a Group router. That's for pool routers to limit how many routees they deploy onto a given node in the cluster.

Here is a sample config that should work for the `frontend` node, based on what I can see. But it'd be helpful if you can add your full HOCON.

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
        deployment {
            /backend {
                router = broadcast-group
                routees.paths = ["/user/backend"]
                cluster {
                  enabled = on
                  allow-local-routees = on
                  use-role = backend
                  }
                }
        }
    }

    remote {
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
        helios.tcp {
          hostname = "127.0.0.1"
          port = 0
        }
    }

    cluster {
      seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ActorSystem@127.0.0.1:1234"] # specify your full frontend seed node address here
      roles = ["frontend"]
      auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! My problem was #3 on your checklist, the deployment section was outside instead of inside of the actor section in the configuration. After correcting that everything is working fine. Thanks again!

Comment: This answer helped me, but I don't understand what `/backend {` refers to within the deployment section. Is it perhaps the name of the actor or the role?

Comment: @Confused `/backend` is the name of the actor. It is a broadcast group router as defined by the config inside the `{ ... }` immediately following its name.